# How to get other computer to connect to my localhost server?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I recently started learning Ruby Sockets and decided to research the topic. I came across the ruby-doc which had some example code that ran smoothly:

This is the example code for the server:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 2000 # Server bound to port 2000

loop do
  client = server.accept    # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts "Hello !"
  client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
  client.close
end
```

And the example code for the client:
    require 'socket'

```
s = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 2000

while line = s.gets # Read lines from socket
  puts line         # and print them
end

s.close             # close socket when done
```

So this ran well but I was wondering how I would get the client to connect if it is running from a different computer. So I attempted to replace the "'localhost'" in the client code with my public IP address courtesy of whatismyip.com, however, when I tried running the new client code on a different computer I merely got a timeout error. I even attempted running the new client code on the same machine running the server but still I got a timeout error.
Does anyone know how I can get this to work properly?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try using the *internal* IP address of your other computer, instead of an address that some random external service gives you. Depending on your OS, use the `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` command to find out what that is. You're likely behind NAT or something where the external IP address is not available for internal connections.

Comment: @GregHewgill, thank you I think it worked. However, it seems the computer hosting the server is blocking the client since I'm getting a "ECONNREFUSED" error.

Comment: Well, that's a step in the right direction. That might either mean that your server isn't running, or some local firewall software on the server is blocking the incoming connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greg Hewgill helped me figure this out:
My first problem was that I was using the wrong address. Greg suggested I check my actual address through the cmd command "ipconfig". The command gave me the actual address that the server was being hosted on. Through this I changed the "'localhost'" in the client code and changed it to the actual IP address. Upon running, I received an error that stated that the server had actively refused the connection. This was fixed by also changing the 'localhost' in the server code to the IP address of the server's machine.
Thank you Greg for the help!